# Asynchronous GET request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app that relies on my app making some simple URL calls for user metrics. For part of the tracking I need to make a server-side call prior to the rendering of my index page. This is achieved by calling a specially formatted URL. Currently I'm achieving this in the following way:

```
url = URI.parse('https://example.tracking.url')
result = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, use_ssl: true, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do
  |http| http.get url.request_uri, 'User-Agent' => 'MyLib v1.2'       
end
```

The loading of my page seems to be, at times, somewhat delayed. Short of it being a Database latency issue I assume it's just that sometimes the URL takes a extra time to respond and that this is a synchronous request. What is the best way to make asynchronous requests in Rails, Threads maybe? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into using a delayed job or Thread.new?

Comment: Would I just need to wrap the bottom three lines with Thread.new do end?

Comment: I would move it to a helper method and then call Thread.new on the helper method. Personally, I like using delayed_job for handling things that may present a delay with the user interface.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the help kobaltz. If you wanna make this an official answer I'd be happy to mark it as having resolved my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into using a delayed job or Thread.new?

I would move it to a helper method and then call Thread.new on the helper method. Personally, I like using delayed_job for handling things that may present a delay with the user interface.